# Exibir dados aleatoriamente de um banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel

Gostaria de deixar de exibir por data e decrescente e fazer ele exibir aleatoriamente ou como eu conheço - randômica.

abaixo o trecho que eu tenho que modificar do arquivo php:

```
public function getNewReleases() {
        return Album::with('artist', 'tracks')
            ->join('artists', 'artists.id', '=', 'albums.artist_id')
            ->orderBy('release_date', 'desc')
            ->limit(40)
            ->select('albums.*')
            ->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não falta a tag laravel ?

Comment: eu preciso apenas alterar esse trecho  -  ->orderBy('release_date', 'desc') ja coloquei ele crescente e funcionou, mas queria ele aleatório essa informação =)

Comment: A minha resposta te ajudou?

Comment: @durtto nao funcionou nao

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar `ORDER BY RAND()` depende da sua versão:

```
Laravel >= 5.2:

User::inRandomOrder()->get();
Laravel 4.2.7 - 5.1:

User::orderByRaw("RAND()")->get();
Laravel 4.0 - 4.2.6:

User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();
Laravel 3:

User::order_by(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();
```

Comment: Não funcionou nada usando oque vc sugeriu.

Comment: Então demonstre o que você tentou, e coloque o resultado.